# MinnowBoardMax: Boot Failed. EFI Misc Device

Tags: debian, debian-jessie, uefi

Upon setting up a new MinnowBoard Max with a stock Debian install, I get the error `Boot Failed. EFI Misc Device` at boot. Searching all over the nets yield little help.

I can start the system fine by waiting for the EFI Shell to start and invoking the grub EFI binary myself: `EFI/debian/grubx64.efi`

I finally did find a solution, but I'm not totally happy with it, and I'm open to advice on better ways of handling it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, which came from the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), is that some EFI Firmwares, apparently including the MinnowBoardMax Firmware, only look for the boot EFI executable at `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`.

Copying the grubx64.efi file to the above path fixes the boot issue.

Comment: `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` is the standard EFI boot path. But what is a MinnowBoard Max and why have you posted this here?

Comment: Perhaps you're right, and this should go on the linux stack exchange. I saw some other similar questions here relating to EFI and booting and thought it would be a reasonable place. A MinnowBoard Max is an embedded x86 linux board, but this advice would apply to anyone seeing a similar error with the stock Debian Jessie install that I used.

Comment: To be clear a minnowboard is a SOC.  Its not quite as powerful as some of the ARM SOCs.